# Django Static files cached

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

My site is in production and whenever I modify my static files it doesn't reflect changes as it seems to be cached somewhere, though I can see the see changes when fresh from network tab in "inspect". **My question is how can I force Django to do it automatically for me on my user's system**

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your browser caches it. Try ctrl + F5 for a hard refresh. You can't force that on a user, though. I imagine best you could do is change the file name to confuse the browser.

Comment: isn't there any other method, like how other websites work?